# React component uses old data from previous API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am using React Query to fetch data from an API I have built. The component is rendering the old data from the previous api call and not updating with new the data from the new api call.
The new data is only rendering when I refresh the page.

Component:

```
export const ProfilePageStats = (props: {
  user: User;
  id: number;
}) => {
  const { chatId } = useParams();

  const { status: subscribeStatus, data: subscribeData } =
    useSubscriptionsWithType(
      chatId ? chatId : "",
      props.id,
      props.user.id,
      "SUBSCRIBE"
    );

  const { status: unsubscribeStatus, data: unsubscribeData } =
    useSubscriptionsWithType(
      chatId ? chatId : "",
      props.id,
      props.user.id,
      "UNSUBSCRIBE"
    );

  if (unsubscribeStatus == "success" && subscribeStatus == "success") {
    console.log("Working", unsubscribeData);
    return (
      <ProfilePageStatsWithData
        user={props.user}
        subscribed={Object.keys(subscribeData).length}
        unsubscribed={Object.keys(unsubscribeData).length}
      />
    );
  }
  if (unsubscribeStatus == "error" && subscribeStatus == "error") {
    console.log("error");
    return <ProfilePageStatsLoading />;
  }
  if (unsubscribeStatus == "loading" && subscribeStatus == "loading") {
    console.log("loading");
    return <ProfilePageStatsLoading />;
  }

  return <ProfilePageStatsLoading />;
};
```

```
export const useSubscriptionsWithType = (
  chatId: string,
  id: number,
  userId: number,
  type: string
) => {
  return useQuery(
    ["subscriptionsWithType"],
    async () => {
      const { data } = await api.get(
        `${chatId}/subscriptions/${id}/${userId}?type=${type}`
      );
      return data;
    },
    {
      enabled: chatId > 0 && userId > 0,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    }
  );
};
```

The component should update to show the new user values but shows the previous user values. If I click out and select a different user entirely it then shows the values for the previously clicked user.

I can see that React Query is fetching with the correct values for the query but the component still renders the old user data?

It turns out that the fetchStatus value is changing to "fetching" but it not actually calling the api. Hence, why its only using the old values?

Comment: Can you share the code for `useSubscriptionsWithType`?

Comment: @AviusX I've added the API calll method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key part of the `useQuery` is what tells the hook when to update.

You only use `["subscriptionsWithType"]` as key, so it will never know that you need to refetch something.

If you add `userId` there, it will update when that changes.

So, using

```
return useQuery(
  ["subscriptionsWithType", userId],
  async () => {
    ...
```

will work.

---

It is likely, that you want all the params, that you use in the url, to be added there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a useEffect and refetching based on the changing user id.

```
useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [props.user.id]);
```